# How should I write simple sequential GETs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Node.js and redis look hot but I'm getting burned. I can't gracefully overcome what seems like a very simple task:

**Given 3 numbers, check if the first two are greater than 10. If yes, print the third number.**

I did accomplish this task with this rather comical script:

```
var http = require("http");
var redis = require("redis");
client = redis.createClient();

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    client.SET("key1", "11");
    client.SET("key2", "9");
    client.SET("key3", "3");

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello\n\n");
    client.GET("key1", function(err, reply) {
        response.write(reply + "\n\n");

        if(parseInt(reply) > 10) {
          client.GET("key2", function(err, reply) {
              response.write(reply + "\n\n");

              if(parseInt(reply) > 10) {
                client.GET("key3", function(err, reply) {
                    response.write(reply + "\n\n");

                    response.end();
                    client.end();
                  });
              } else {
                response.end();
                client.end();
              }

            });
        } else {
          response.end();
          client.end();
        }
      });
  }).listen(8000);
```

The few things I noticed are:

- is it necessary to nest each time I want a new GET?
- `response.end()` needs to called somewhere for the `write`s to appear. How do I avoid repeating them in the `else` blocks?

Then I tried this style of querying the DB:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {

client.SET("key1", "11");
client.SET("key2", "9");
client.SET("key3", "3");

var key1 = 0;
var key2 = 0;
var key3 = 0;

response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello\n\n");
client.GET("key1", function(err, reply) {
        response.write(reply + "\n\n");
        key1 = parseInt(reply);
    });

client.GET("key2", function(err, reply) {
        response.write(reply + "\n\n");
        key2 = parseInt(reply);
    });

client.GET("key3", function(err, reply) {
        response.write(reply + "\n\n");
        key3 = parseInt(reply);
    });

response.write(key1 + "\n\n");
response.write(key2 + "\n\n");
response.write(key3 + "\n\n");

response.end();
client.end();
```

After some reading and some thought, my explanation is that the code gets to the `response.write`s before the asynchronous GETs return, and then the response is closed so the inner writes never happen. At least I noticed from the first example that the SETs can be called easily, but I don't know (and it doesn't seem to matter) if they are actually set in that order.

So, perhaps I'm doing something that is not suitable for node and redis. And I must be missing something basic and obvious. What do I need to do to level up?

Or tell me I have to go back to PhpMyAdmin :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at async it can help you organize your code
https://github.com/caolan/async
Hope this helps